# Request TimedOut due to Redistribution : Oracle Coherence Cache

Tags: oracle, timeout, oracle-coherence

We are facing this error very rarely after about 30 minutes from our weekend coherence cache reboot. Any pointers will be helpful to debug. We are trying to find the ROOT Cause

**(thread=DistributedCache): Transferring 382KB of backup[1] for PartitionSet{55} to member 2
(thread=Proxy:ExtendTcpProxyService:TcpAcceptorWorker:8): An exception occurred while processing a GetRequest for Service=Proxy:ExtendTcpProxyService:TcpAcceptor: com.tangosol.net.RequestTimeoutException: Request timed-out due to a redistribution
        at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$BinaryMap.waitForPartitionRedistribution(PartitionedCache.CDB:131)**

Answer (score 0):

There is most probably a serious network problem there. Coherence can transfer 120MB/s on 1Gbe, over 1GB/s on 10Gbe, and almost 4GB/s on Infiniband, so a fraction of a megabyte causing a time-out means there's a serious issue.

Also, it appears that you have a request time-out configured (I don't believe that is on by default). You may need to up that setting.